# how to write object-oriented jQuery plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, event-driven

So I have a bit of experience writing normal plugins to do whatever, but I want to move towards an object-based event-driven system that can be more dynamic and customizable for the end user. For the sake of my question I have written up a small plugin that simply highlights text on the `$(selector).hover()` event.

Here is the JS/jQuery:

```
(function($) {
  var objs = [];

  var defaults = {
       color: "blue",
      normal: "black",
     onHover: function() {},
    offHover: function() {}
  };

  var Text = function (settings, self) {
    this.self     = $(self);
    this.color    = settings.color;
    this.normal   = settings.normal;
    this.show     = function () { this.self.css( "color", this.color); }
    this.noShow   = function () { this.self.css( "color", this.normal);}
    this.onHover  = settings.onHover;
    this.offHover = settings.offHover;
  };

  $.fn.myPlugin = function(opts) {
    this.each(function() {
      var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, opts);

      $(this).data('index', objs.push(new Text(settings, this)) -1);
      // I feel like this should be handled differently, maybe
      // attach an event to the inside of the object?
  });

    this.hover(
      function(e) {
        objs[$(e.currentTarget).data('index')].show();
        objs[$(e.currentTarget).data('index')].onHover();
      }, function(e) {
        objs[$(e.currentTarget).data('index')].noShow();
        objs[$(e.currentTarget).data('index')].offHover();
    });
  };
}(jQuery));
```

Basically, this line...

```
(this).data('index', objs.push(new Text(settings, this)) -1);
```

...could be handled much differently and more efficiently. The problem is I need a global array that holds all objects generated by the plugin. So if I call the plugin twice on two separate 'p' tags, then there should be two objects in that array, so on so forth. Right now, that aspect is 'working' but I need to store a reference to what index that object is at by attaching an 'index' data type to the DOM element. This feels like a very wrong way to have an object oriented approach. So how can I, on an event, trigger the function...

```
myObject.show();
```

...where myObject is a reference to the element in the array that I want to highlight.

I hope my question is clear, it is a weird issue to describe I feel, but also a very powerful concept if it can be applied the way I am thinking of it. Let me know if anything is unclear and I would be happy to clarify.

Comment: You sure are complicating this !

Comment: I would agree in a simple application like this, but I am applying this concept to a much larger project where it makes sense because of the specific use case. This is just to describe the issue in as simple a way I can think of

Comment: Seems really simple to me -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/5g0rhjyd/1/

Comment: Yes but now the method has been pulled out of the object, this moves the solution farther from a purely object-oriented approach which is where I would like to be. That would certainly work, just not the way I need it to.

Comment: And that's the "you're complicating it" part. Why do you need to create new instances of an object that has no inheritance and no prototyped properties, and as jQuery already solves all this with `return this.each(...` there's really no need to go mucking about with "object oriented" complicated code to do simple things. Put it in the plugin, write it the "regular way", and it works fine.

Comment: Because in my project where this issue exists, I do have a far more complicated system that needs to be both independent to itself and  considered a part of a group depending on the circumstances, it is a highly dynamic system that is far easier to manage when created through an object oriented approach. This situation is extremely simple and does not benefit at all, I agree, but it also very clearly shows what I am trying to achieve and make sit easier for me to describe the issue. If I can get the concept working on this plugin, then porting that to my actual plugin is not  very difficult.

Comment: Ask yourself, have you ever seen a jQuery plugin that works that way? If you just have to make things hard for yourself, do it so you can execute it like `$(this).myPlugin('show')` inside the hover states etc. That's how jQuery solves issues like this, for instance in jQuery UI etc. Functions should be generic, you shouldn't be creating custom functions for every element that runs through your plugin, it's just bad practice.

Comment: That actually might work, I'll give it a shot

Comment: @adeneo, While your specific suggestion did not fit my code exactly, it did lead me to find the answer I was looking for. I have posted it as the answer to this question so others may reference it. I appreciate the help you gave as I would not have gotten unstuck from my rut of thinking if not for your comments persuading me not to go down the path I was on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In doing a bit more reading and trying to understand how object oriented programming works in respect to javascript, jquery and the DOM, I stumbled upon my own answer. Here is what the code looks like for anyone that may have been as confused as I was going into plugin development:

```
(function($) {
  var defaults = {
       color: "blue",
      normal: "black",
     onHover: function() {},
    offHover: function() {}
  };

  var Text = function(opts, self) {
    var settings  = $.extend({}, defaults, opts);
    this.self     = $(self);
    this.color    = settings.color;
    this.normal   = settings.normal;
    this.onHover  = settings.onHover;
    this.offHover = settings.offHover;
    this.show     = function () { this.self.css( "color", this.color);  };
    this.noShow   = function () { this.self.css( "color", this.normal); };
  };

  $.fn.myPlugin = function(opts) {
    this.each(function() {
      this.text = new Text(opts, this);
    });

    this.hover(
      function() {
        this.text.show();
        this.text.onHover.call();
      }, function() {
        this.text.noShow();
        this.text.offHover.call();
      });
  };
}(jQuery));
```

The issue I was dealing with was an appropriate understanding of name space and closure, as well as what things you can and cannot do with DOM elements. I am not sure if this is the common way or not, but it is working very well for my uses and might work for yours.